# PHP parse error

Tags: php, syntax

firstof all, i excuse in advance, this error may be a simple one. 
But i slept like 4 hour this night... :'(

```
<?php echo url_for('@news_read/id=?'.$news_item->getId()) ?>
```

outputs a syntax error and i don't see where it is 
(i wouldn't see an elephant right now...)

Thank you

Comment: How nice of you to give us the error message you get ...

Comment: Great, i refreshes it to show you the error.... and the error is gone.... It means that i have to go to bed ... NOW.

sry guys for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue fix after clearing the cache. Sry for disturbing you.

Answer (score 0):

end it with a semi-colon ;

Comment: this isn't required. The last semicolon may be omitted if you close the `<?php` tag (i.e. you can't omit both the semicolon and the closing tag.)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be (at least give it a try)

```
?id=
```

Normally that's how you pass variables on an URL but I don't quite get your syntax.

Comment: Could be using mod_rewrite or something similar.

Comment: yeah i think it's due to symfony (framework)